# get shared preference from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

this is my settings activity which has got one switch:

```
settings_inputs_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.settings_inputs_switch);
settings_prefs = getSharedPreferences("settings_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
settings_inputs_switch.setChecked(settings_prefs.getBoolean("switch1_state",true  ));
settings_inputs_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (settings_inputs_switch.isChecked()){
        settings_prefs = getSharedPreferences("settings_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings_prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("switch1_state", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else {
        settings_prefs = getSharedPreferences("settings_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings_prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("switch1_state", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
 });
```

how can i get this shared preference value in main activity to do some job based on the value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is in your `MainActivity` read the value of the preference in `onResume()`. This should get you the latest value each time you get to `MainActivity` from anywhere.

To read the value, you do it similarly as you write them. In your `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("settings_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean switchState1 = prefs.getBoolean("switch1_state", false);
    // Do more stuff
}
```

(fact: "settings_prefs" is an xml file within your app's local storage)

Answer (score 0):

as stated above one trick i use is to check for changes in onResume() method

Answer (score 0):

You can read preference valve like this in any activity.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("settings_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean value = sharedPreference.getBoolean("switch1_state",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

**SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)**

Retrieve and hold the contents of the preferences file '**name**', returning a SharedPreferences through which you can retrieve and modify its values. Only one instance of the SharedPreferences object is returned to any callers for the same name, meaning they will see each other's edits as soon as they are made.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("settings_prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean switchState= sharedPreference.getBoolean("switch1_state",false);
```